# Obtener value de un elemento con querySelector en SPA con vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando una SPA con webpack y vanillaJS, tengo un router que va llamando a las distintas pages del SPA. Cuando renderizo un page que tiene un input y un button quiero obtener el value del input con querySelector pero es undefined, supongo que es porque aun no se grafica el html. De que forma podria insertar un eventListener al boton para capturar ese value?

```js
const Home =  () => {
  const view = `
    <div class="Characters"> 
      <button onclick="send()">Ingresar<button>
      </div> 
  `;
  return view;
};

const send = () => {
  console.log('Enviar codigo a buscar en la DB');
};

export default Home;
```

Cuando ejecuto: Uncaught ReferenceError: send is not defined

***Solución:***
He agregado el input en un template anterior y en el boton he agregado en onClick

```
<button onClick="location.href='#/'+document.querySelector('#code').value">ingesar</button>
```

Comment: Deberías compartir lo que haz avanzado de código para que te ayudemos mejor.

Comment: Gracias, ya inserté el código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podes agregar directamente el evento onclick al boton que carga, y que este sea el responsable de tomar los valores de tu imput y proporcionarlo a tu app.

```
<button onclick="send()">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: He probado de esa manera pero igual. He añadido el codigo a la pregunta

Comment: Gracias !! ayudó tu sugerencia